# use of React.Lazy for services (non-component) type of code

Tags: reactjs, lazy-loading

Per documentation, React.Lazy needs to be wrapped in a `<suspense>`. Can I use `React.Lazy` to lazily load a service which exports a function?

```js
    const actionsList = React.lazy(() => import('@pkg/actions-list-service'));
```

and the **action-List-service** exports a function in a **.ts** file. What does React recommended way for lazily loading non-component type of code?
This is the error I get trying to lazily load the service code I got this error:

```
Type 'Promise<{ default: typeof import("D:/services/actions-list-service/dist/types"); useActionsList: () => (itemElement: HTMLElement | null | undefined) => readonly ActionsListItem[]; }>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<{ default: ComponentType<any>; }>'.
```

Answer (score 2):

If you check the source of `React.lazy()`, you'll see that it's geared towards component rendering, as you could guess. In order to lazy load something, you can just use async import:

```js
// example code, to show possible solution

const moduleMap = {
  module1: () => import('./module1.js'),
  module2: () => import('./module2.js')
}

function doSomething(moduleName) {
  // You might call this one in useEffect() for example
  const module = moduleMap[moduleName]
  if (module) {
    module().then(({default: actualModule, member1}) => {
      // use the module members
    })
  }
}
```

That will allow lazy loading and possibly code splitting as well.

Answer (score 2):

If we want to **trigger React Suspense loader**, then we have to provide a component that will load the independent library.

For example I want to lazy load the [html5-qrcode](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html5-qrcode) `Html5Qrcode` module that it's 314K (gzipped 93.5K).

We create a loader component that will have an `onLoaded` callback prop and it just returns the module like:

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { Html5Qrcode } from 'html5-qrcode/esm/html5-qrcode';

export default function Html5QrcodeLoader({ onLoaded }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    onLoaded(Html5Qrcode);
  }, []);
  return null;
}
```

Then we import that component using `React.lazy` like:

```
const Html5QrcodeLoader = React.lazy(() =>
  import(
    '@components/Html5QrcodeLoader' /* webpackChunkName: "Html5QrcodeLoader" */
  )
);
```

And now we can use the loader to our component like this:

```
export default function QrCodeScanner() {
  const [Html5Qrcode, setHtml5Qrcode] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!Html5Qrcode) {
      return;
    }

    // Use lazy loaded module Html5Qrcode
  }, [Html5Qrcode]);

  const handleHtml5QrcodeLoaded = module => {
    // Careful, always do it using a function,
    // else the module itself will be initialized!
    setHtml5Qrcode(() => module);
  };

  if (!Html5Qrcode) {
    // Lazy load it
    return <Html5QrcodeLoader onLoaded={handleHtml5QrcodeLoaded} />;
  }

  log('Html5Qrcode loaded');

  // Now render

  return (
    <div>
      <div>QrCodeScanner</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```